# Numeric keyboard with dot-key in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a problem with numeric keyboard . I want to replace comma-key to dot-key. I tried use 'decimal-pad', 'number-pad', 'numeric' for prop keyboardType of TextInput but it doesn't work.
So is there any solution for that ?

I'm using React Native 0.46.4

Thanks a lots

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXwrC.jpg)

Comment: You are sure `keyboardType = 'numeric'` didn't work (you WANT a dot, instead of a comma right)?

Comment: You are missing the point. If there is comma, it means the user language uses comma as a decimal separator. Instead of trying to change that, you should handle comma in the input.

Comment: @RyanTurnbull yes. Comma was still shown with 'numeric'

Comment: @Sulthan Thanks a lots. I got it

Comment: @Sulthan , there are situations where you'd always want dot.  E.g. input is an IP address.